# Java Infinite loop/calls

Tags: java

Hi 
I bumped into this problem this morning (I've already found a work around) but I'm curious to why my code is not working as I wanted

```
    public class classA

    //(1)
    public void function(GL10 gl){

             function(gl,useGLUtilsBool, useMipMapBool);
         }
    //(2)
         public void function(GL10 gl,boolean useGLUtils, boolean 
    useMipMap){
             generateTexture(gl, useGLUtils, useMipMap);
         }
    }

    @Override
    public class classB extends 
    classA{
    //(3)
         public void function(GL10 gl, boolean useGLUtils, boolean 
    useMipMap) {
             function(gl);
         }
    //(4)
    @Override    
     public void function(GL10 gl) {
             super.function(gl);

         }
```

Normally it should do (3)->(4)->(1)->(2)
but instead I get (3)->(4)->(1)->(3)->(4)->(1)...

what I don't get is why classA function(...) (1) would call (3) and not (2)

Comment: Welcome to polymorphism.

Comment: Yep I've been playing with polymorphism, I just didn't expect that one ^^(I know we never expect bugs, they just invite themselves)

Comment: Note: if the function() was static, it would behave the way you describe because you don't get polymorphism with static methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of inheritance and [polymorphism](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#Java). You have overridden (mark this with `@Override`) the `function(GL10 gl, boolean useGLUtils, boolean useMipMap)` method in the subclass, so each time this method is called on an instance of class `B`, the overriding method will be invoked, instead of the one in the superclass

Comment: I actually just forgot the @Override when I wrote the question

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with a design decision of Java, making all public methods [virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function) by default. In a language like C++ where you explicitly have to declare functions as virtual you'd get the behavior you expected with the code above. 
In Java however, the call will always end up going to the method furthest down the inheritance chain, unless you use the super prefix to force it to call a method that's higher up.